# Show a block on a certain URL with wildcard

Tags: blocks

How do I show a `<div>` inside page.tpl.php, on every page except for URLs that start with "audio/track"?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is not a node (is a landing page, view, panel etc) you can use the function arg

```
if(arg(0) != "audio" && arg(1) != "track") {
  print "<div></div>";
}
```

Or if is a node you can make the conditional using a taxonomy or using the node type.

```
if(arg(0) == "node" && is_numeric(arg(1)) && $node->type != "your-node-type" ){
  print "<div></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration or your block you've a "Page specific visibility settings". Choose the "Show on every page except the listed pages." option and in the textarea below add your url.

In your case it will be something like that `/*/audio/track`

In the code, you can directly use the function [drupal_match_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/6), you get the current path with [request_uri](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/6) function and in the patterns you add the example given above.

Comment: Sorry but i kinda said, The <DIV>content</DIV> not the drupal block.

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your request.